# Is there any other method besides inflection point to find the origin of positive rates?

Tags: r, data-visualization, frequency

So I have this dataset that looks like this.

Income is the amount of income customers at a grocery stores reportedly make.

Campaign is whether the customer accepted the campaign, 1 if they did, 0 otherwise.

"Accepted or not" is just another way of expressing Campaign for the last variable.

CumSumAcceptance is the running sum of the "Accepted or not" column.

I want to analyze the data set and find out at what what income point does the ratio of response to the campaign starts favoring the people who accepted the campaign.

From the graph it looks like the rate starts to trend positive at around 80k income.

What are some things I should look at or try to analyze this.

| Income | Campaign | Accepted or not | CumSumAcceptance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 0 | -1 | -1 |
| 2000 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3000 | 0 | -1 | -1 |
| 4000 | 0 | -1 | -2 |
| 5000 | 0 | -1 | -3 |
| 6000 | 1 | 1 | -2 |

```r
x = dfEDA$Income
y =dfEDA$CSAccept
plot(x,y,type="l")
lo <- loess(y~x)
xl <- seq(min(x),max(x), (max(x) - min(x))/444)
out = predict(lo,xl)
lines(xl, out, col='red', lwd=2)

infl <- c(FALSE, diff(diff(out)>0)!=0)

points(xl[infl ], out[infl ], col="blue")
```

The code I used is as above and have no issues with it but I don't know if this is the best route to take.

Plot of Income and Cumulative sum!
[image: Plot of Income and Cumulative sum]